# Why is Node's mongoose telling me that undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Node script that will connect to an external server's MongoDB and insert a user. Basic stuff that I have found in several dozen tutorials using localhost. The issue that has come up is that when following those tutorials, no matter what I have tried I seem to be getting a TypeError: undefined is not a function message. I know that this is due to me being new to both Mongo and Node, but knowing that unfortunately doesn't make this easier to figure out.

The code that I have does not have any webpage involved and is just supposed to be the back-end connection in this case. The code is as follows:

```
    var User = require('/var/www/html/testing/folder1/User.js');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


    mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:(Server Admin Password)@(I.P address of the server)/(Database Name)');

    var newUser = User({
      _id: "KM529",
      email: "emailname@email.com",
      name: "John Smith",
      password: "password",
      photo: "a picture url"
    });

    newUser.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      }

      console.log('User save successfully');
    });
```

The above is the file that is actually being run. The additional required file is:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    // Creates a schema to be used for all user documents
    var userSchema = new Schema({
      _id: { type:String, required: true, unique: true },
      email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true} ,
      photo: String,
    });

    var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

    module.exports = User;
```

I have already looked at 15+ similar stackoverflow questions and yet none of them have allowed me to solve this issue. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be forever grateful.

Edit: The error that I am getting is:

```
    /var/www/html/testing/pokemon/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:282
      var promise = new Promise.ES6(function(resolve, reject) {
            ^
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
at NativeConnection.Connection.open (/var/www/html/testing/pokemon/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:282:17)
at Mongoose.connect (/var/www/html/testing/folder1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:241:47)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/testing/pokemon/test.js:8:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: What line is the error coming from? It's pretty difficult to tell you what's going wrong without knowing where the problem is

Comment: I clarified above with the full error text that I get.

Comment: Which versions of node and mongoose are you using? Also why override the `mongoose.Promise` with the `global.Promise` ? That might be the issue?

Comment: The issue I am having appears to be one with the server I am trying to connect to. i have now installed Mongo on the local server to test out connecting to that and it works, though still gives me the deprecated promise library warning. The override was done to take care of the aforementioned warning that I get every time it is run

Comment: Please include the node version. I see you are using mongoose 5.x+ like https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/5.0-Deprecation-Warnings but what version of `node -v`?  Perhaps try replacing mpromise with bluebird?

Comment: Currently using NodeJS v0.10.29

Answer (score 2):

Did some debugging using the node repl:

```
> var m = require('mongoose')
undefined
> m.Promise
{ [Function: Promise] ES6: [Function], SUCCESS: 'complete', FAILURE: 'err' }
> m.Promise.ES6
[Function]
> global.Promise
[Function: Promise]
> global.Promise.ES6
undefined
```

`global.Promise.ES6` doesn't exist using node 6.2.2

Remove this line:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Comment: That seems to just change the error from the module based one to one that tells me that the mpromise library is deprecated and then does nothing beyond that. Were you able to actually perform an insert with the code you had tested with?